Why are there no color ramps in QGIS LTR?
I have a new machine and loaded the current QGIS LTR 3.34.11. When I tried to symbolise a raster layer there were no default color ramps to select from?


See above the default color ramps on my old machine on a previous QGIS version

The color ramp should be there, your installation seem to have a problem you should try to reinstall

Render type is Singleband pseudocolor, right?

Yes palleted/unique values works fine

Yes singleband pseudocolor

Tried reinstalling with same result

I changed profile and can now use the default color ramp

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
